# npm request.post giving error everytime but the same post works with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, post, http-post

I am trying to make a post request from express js to an api, from serverside.

Here is the code for it

```
request.post({
                url: $url,
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {id : '392', sid: 'abc'}
                }, function(error, response, body){
                    console.log(response.statusCode);
                    console.log(body);
            });
```

this always returns with a response statusCode 500;

On the other hand, I tried the same post request from server side using Jquery.

Here is the code for it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: $url,
    crossDomain:true,
    data: {
        id : $id,
        sid: $sid
    },
    type: "POST",
    // dataType: "json",

    //on success
    success: function(response){
        //do something after something is received data
    },
    //on error
    error: function(jqXHR, exception){
        //bad request
        console.log(jqXHR.status);
        console.log(exception);
    }
});
```

The $url and all the other variables are same in both the cases. Though, I get proper response and status code 200 for the post I do with Jquery, unlike the one I do with npm request module.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: i think the format to call post request is `request.post('http://service.com/api', {form:{key:'value'}})` as per https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what about this code?

I also don't seem to find any reference to the 'crossDomain' option in the request.js docs

```
var request = require('request');
request.post(
    {
        headers: {'content-type':'application/json'},
        url: $url,
        form: {id : '392', sid: 'abc'}
    },
    function(error, response, body){
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        console.log(body)
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`request`](https://github.com/request/request) and `$.ajax` don't have the same [options](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) when being called. You can send the request body using the `body` property in the options object passed. Additionally, there is the convenience boolean `json` to add the `Content-Type:application/json` header to the request, serialize the request body as JSON and to automatically parse the response body as JSON.

```
const request = require('request')

request({
  url: $url,
  method: 'POST',
  body: {id: '392', sid: 'abc'},
  json: true
}, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
    console.log(err)
    return
  }

  // handle response
  console.log(response)      
})
```